# PHP Mail Not Working on localhost (Mac)

Tags: php, email, localhost

When I try to send mail in php from an HTML form on my localhost on Mac operation times out then the connection refuses and finally the server refuses. I have no idea what to do. I had tried google searching and I could not get anything. Help! Oh and here is the error log it might be useful:

```
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/master[5349]: fatal: open lock file pid/master.pid: unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/master[5350]: daemon started -- version 3.2.2, configuration /etc/postfix
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 5A2D0201224655: from=<_www@Owens-MBP.fios-router.home>, size=451, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 459A320131301F: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 43595201224693: from=<_www@Owens-MBP.fios-router.home>, size=451, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 6E34D20131345A: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=489, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: C7D90201316CAC: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: A19D720131341C: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 9BA2A201312DE9: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=489, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: D6841201313733: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 36733201313448: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=489, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 81E92201317892: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 4A0B520131372D: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:59 Owens-MBP postfix/pickup[5351]: 777F02013E5046: uid=501 from=<owenwang>
Jun 11 16:46:59 Owens-MBP postfix/cleanup[5353]: 777F02013E5046: message-id=<20180611204659.777F02013E5046@Owens-MBP.fios-router.home>
Jun 11 16:46:59 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 777F02013E5046: from=<owenwang@Owens-MBP.fios-router.home>, size=410, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:47:08 Owens-MBP postfix/master[5361]: fatal: open lock file pid/master.pid: unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jun 11 16:47:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5357]: connect to mx1.mail.icloud.com[17.57.8.139]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5356]: connect to mx2.mail.icloud.com[17.142.163.11]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5358]: connect to mx3.mail.icloud.com[17.57.8.141]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5355]: connect to mx4.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.66]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5359]: connect to mx5.mail.icloud.com[17.57.8.138]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:58 Owens-MBP postfix/master[5350]: master exit time has arrived
Jun 11 16:47:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5357]: connect to mx2.mail.icloud.com[17.142.163.14]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5358]: connect to mx6.mail.icloud.com[17.57.8.144]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5356]: connect to mx4.mail.icloud.com[17.133.229.9]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5355]: connect to mx2.mail.icloud.com[17.142.163.14]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5359]: connect to mx2.mail.icloud.com[17.57.8.135]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5357]: connect to mx3.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.65]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5358]: connect to mx5.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.69]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5355]: connect to mx1.mail.icloud.com[17.142.163.13]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5356]: connect to mx5.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.69]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5359]: connect to mx1.mail.icloud.com[17.57.8.139]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5357]: connect to mx6.mail.icloud.com[17.57.8.144]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5358]: connect to mx5.mail.icloud.com[17.133.229.11]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5355]: connect to mx6.mail.icloud.com[17.178.97.75]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5359]: connect to mx6.mail.icloud.com[17.133.229.12]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5356]: connect to mx1.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.10]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/master[5390]: fatal: open lock file pid/master.pid: unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/master[5389]: daemon started -- version 3.2.2, configuration /etc/postfix
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 5A2D0201224655: skipped, still being delivered
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 459A320131301F: skipped, still being delivered
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 43595201224693: skipped, still being delivered
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 777F02013E5046: from=<owenwang@Owens-MBP.fios-router.home>, size=410, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 6E34D20131345A: skipped, still being delivered
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: C7D90201316CAC: skipped, still being delivered
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: A19D720131341C: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 9BA2A201312DE9: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=489, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: D6841201313733: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 36733201313448: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=489, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 81E92201317892: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 4A0B520131372D: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:11 Owens-MBP postfix/pickup[5391]: BC1292013E5149: uid=501 from=<owenwang>
Jun 11 16:49:11 Owens-MBP postfix/cleanup[5393]: BC1292013E5149: message-id=<20180611204911.BC1292013E5149@Owens-MBP.fios-router.home>
Jun 11 16:49:11 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: BC1292013E5149: from=<owenwang@Owens-MBP.fios-router.home>, size=410, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:20 Owens-MBP postfix/master[5401]: fatal: open lock file pid/master.pid: unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jun 11 16:49:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5357]: connect to mx3.mail.icloud.com[17.142.163.12]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:49:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5355]: connect to mx4.mail.icloud.com[17.178.97.73]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:49:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5356]: connect to mx1.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.9]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:49:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5359]: connect to mx3.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.65]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:49:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5358]: connect to mx5.mail.icloud.com[17.178.97.74]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/master[5349]: fatal: open lock file pid/master.pid: unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/master[5350]: daemon started -- version 3.2.2, configuration /etc/postfix
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 5A2D0201224655: from=<_www@Owens-MBP.fios-router.home>, size=451, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 459A320131301F: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 43595201224693: from=<_www@Owens-MBP.fios-router.home>, size=451, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 6E34D20131345A: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=489, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: C7D90201316CAC: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: A19D720131341C: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 9BA2A201312DE9: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=489, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: D6841201313733: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 36733201313448: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=489, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 81E92201317892: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:58 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 4A0B520131372D: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:46:59 Owens-MBP postfix/pickup[5351]: 777F02013E5046: uid=501 from=<owenwang>
Jun 11 16:46:59 Owens-MBP postfix/cleanup[5353]: 777F02013E5046: message-id=<20180611204659.777F02013E5046@Owens-MBP.fios-router.home>
Jun 11 16:46:59 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5352]: 777F02013E5046: from=<owenwang@Owens-MBP.fios-router.home>, size=410, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:47:08 Owens-MBP postfix/master[5361]: fatal: open lock file pid/master.pid: unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jun 11 16:47:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5357]: connect to mx1.mail.icloud.com[17.57.8.139]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5356]: connect to mx2.mail.icloud.com[17.142.163.11]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5358]: connect to mx3.mail.icloud.com[17.57.8.141]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5355]: connect to mx4.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.66]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5359]: connect to mx5.mail.icloud.com[17.57.8.138]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:58 Owens-MBP postfix/master[5350]: master exit time has arrived
Jun 11 16:47:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5357]: connect to mx2.mail.icloud.com[17.142.163.14]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5358]: connect to mx6.mail.icloud.com[17.57.8.144]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5356]: connect to mx4.mail.icloud.com[17.133.229.9]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5355]: connect to mx2.mail.icloud.com[17.142.163.14]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:47:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5359]: connect to mx2.mail.icloud.com[17.57.8.135]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5357]: connect to mx3.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.65]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5358]: connect to mx5.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.69]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5355]: connect to mx1.mail.icloud.com[17.142.163.13]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5356]: connect to mx5.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.69]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5359]: connect to mx1.mail.icloud.com[17.57.8.139]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5357]: connect to mx6.mail.icloud.com[17.57.8.144]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5358]: connect to mx5.mail.icloud.com[17.133.229.11]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5355]: connect to mx6.mail.icloud.com[17.178.97.75]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5359]: connect to mx6.mail.icloud.com[17.133.229.12]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:48:58 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5356]: connect to mx1.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.10]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/master[5390]: fatal: open lock file pid/master.pid: unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/master[5389]: daemon started -- version 3.2.2, configuration /etc/postfix
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 5A2D0201224655: skipped, still being delivered
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 459A320131301F: skipped, still being delivered
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 43595201224693: skipped, still being delivered
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 777F02013E5046: from=<owenwang@Owens-MBP.fios-router.home>, size=410, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 6E34D20131345A: skipped, still being delivered
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: C7D90201316CAC: skipped, still being delivered
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: A19D720131341C: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 9BA2A201312DE9: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=489, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: D6841201313733: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 36733201313448: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=489, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 81E92201317892: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:10 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: 4A0B520131372D: from=<_www@Owens-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=421, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:11 Owens-MBP postfix/pickup[5391]: BC1292013E5149: uid=501 from=<owenwang>
Jun 11 16:49:11 Owens-MBP postfix/cleanup[5393]: BC1292013E5149: message-id=<20180611204911.BC1292013E5149@Owens-MBP.fios-router.home>
Jun 11 16:49:11 Owens-MBP postfix/qmgr[5392]: BC1292013E5149: from=<owenwang@Owens-MBP.fios-router.home>, size=410, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 11 16:49:20 Owens-MBP postfix/master[5401]: fatal: open lock file pid/master.pid: unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jun 11 16:49:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5357]: connect to mx3.mail.icloud.com[17.142.163.12]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:49:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5355]: connect to     mx4.mail.icloud.com[17.178.97.73]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:49:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5356]: connect to mx1.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.9]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:49:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5359]: connect to mx3.mail.icloud.com[17.172.34.65]:25: Operation timed out
Jun 11 16:49:28 Owens-MBP postfix/smtp[5358]: connect to mx5.mail.icloud.com[17.178.97.74]:25: Operation timed out
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: If you open a terminal can you send mail manually using the `mail` command, `mailx`, or similar?

Comment: @ivanivan I don't know how to mail manually.